# Best Windows scripting Tool

Tags: performance, vba, scripting, ms-word, windows-scripting

I've got a simple task, take a text file and duplicate each word in the text file.  So if the text file was "I love pancakes", my output needs to be "I I love love pancakes pancakes"

I've tried using Word 2013 and VBA.  Here's my code:

```
Sub HLSConvert()
    Set docNew = Documents.Add
    Set origDoc = Documents.Open("c:\test\AllWords.txt")
    Dim r As String
    For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        For Each W In sentence.Words
            r = W + W
            docNew.Content.InsertAfter r
            DoEvents
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Unfortunately VBA is REALLY slow.  The text files I'm working on are a thousand pages long and it takes VBA like 2 hours to duplicate a file that large.  So I'm hoping someone here can help.  Is there a better tool\language I can use to accomplish this?  Or can someone suggest a improvements to my VBA code to speed the process along?

Comment: Suggestions: Don't use ActiveDocument - Word always needs to calculate which is the ActiveDocument. You've set a variable to the two documents, use that object, instead (origDoc). Concatenate the modified content in a string, rather than writing it back to the document (docNew) in the loop. Each time you address an object, it's slower. Write the entire string to the document once you're done. Fully use the object model, rather than make VBA guess what you mean: r  = r & W.Text & W.Text (note the & instead of +) Are you sure you need DoEvents?

Comment: Don't open a txt file in Word as a Word doc. Use FSO and TextStream to handle them. You can also do this from a VBS file, and then you don't need MS Office at all for the task. Google is your friend. :)

Comment: `r = r & " " & W & " " & W`

Comment: Should punctuation marks be duplicated as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of RegEx based code for words duplication. It doesn't need MS Office installed, you may use it as WSH VB script, saved to .VBS file. Also it works in VBA environment.

```vb
Sub WordsDuplicate(strSource, strTarget)
    ' strSource - full path to the source text file
    ' strTarget - full path to the target text file
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If .FileExists(strSource) Then
            ' read source text file
            With .OpenTextFile(strSource, 1, False, 0) ' -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
                strCont = ""
                If Not .AtEndOfStream Then strCont = .ReadAll
                .Close
            End With
            ' duplicate
            With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = True
                .Pattern = "(\b\w+\b)"
                strRes = .Replace(strCont, "$1 $1")
            End With
            ' write target text file
            With .OpenTextFile(strTarget, 2, True, 0)
                .Write (strRes)
                .Close
            End With
            t3 = timer
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I've taken as a sample the text containing 572614 words, file size 3.11 MB, ANSI charset. The result timings are: read source text file 180 msec, duplicate 320 msec, write target text file 39 msec. About 540 msec total.